# slick slider not inititating properly

Tags: slick.js

I'm trying to implement a slick slider for the first time but it's not working, I don't get any error in the console. In the demo provided the div of each slide is given the following attributes on initiation:

```
<div class="slick-slide"  style="width: 560px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 900; opacity: 1;">
```

but in my slider these attributes aren't given and nothing happens. The following is my code:

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
</head>

<div class="slider fade">
                    <div><div class="image"><img src="img/fonz1.png"/></div></div>
                    <div><div class="image"><img src="img/fonz2.png"/></div></div>
                    <div><div class="image"><img src="img/fonz3.png"/></div></div>
                </div>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.fade').slick({
                       dots: true,
                      infinite: true,
                      speed: 500,
                      fade: true,
                      slide: '> div',
                      cssEase: 'linear'
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: The slick tag is misleading. It is for the slick DB API for scala not for the slider!

Comment: @user2346536 Yup there are several questions which use this incorrectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't get my Slick slider to work at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290692/i-cant-get-my-slick-slider-to-work-at-all)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the the extra `div`:

Change:

```
<div><div class="image"><img src="img/fonz1.png"/></div></div>
```

To:

```
<div class="image"><img src="img/fonz1.png"/></div>
```

`class="image"` is optional

Answer (score 1):

Maybe little late but get rid of

```
slide: '> div',
```

inside your slick function. You don't need it.