# I can't get my Slick slider to work at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I'm trying to get a fading, Slick slider to work on my website.  But I'm having no luck.  This is Slick: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

If you scroll down, you'll see the instructions on how to implement.  I've attached my screenshot, so hopefully someone can see what I'm doing wrong.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="fade">
   <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){       
$('.fade').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  fade: true,
  slide: '> div',
  cssEase: 'linear'
});
    
        });
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm new to Javascript and Jquery so I feel like I'm messing something up there.

When I load my page, all I see are the 3 test images, one below the other.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle of your code, to see if there are any errors with it?

Comment: Post your code, not a screenshot of it! It is just simple copy and paste, easy and quick.

Comment: Added the code.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Slick Slider Working Example
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Slick-Slider

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in the `slide` setting (element query to select the slider)

For example changing:

```
$('.fade').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  fade: true,
  slide: '> div',
  cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

to

```
$('.fade').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 700,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    arrows:false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
 });
```

Works, just play around with the settings.
You were defining `slide` as `> div` (inmediate children of div), so if you remove it (defaults to `div`), it works.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="fade">
   <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[ img 1 ]" /></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.11/slick.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){       
$('.fade').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 700,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    arrows:false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
 });
    
        });
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was so frustrating!

Comment: Slick Slider Working Example
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Slick-Slider